# Binding stops updating

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, flot

I've been trying to create a custom binding for updating flot charts and it seems like it works when it first loads, but as I navigate around it quits.

Here's the scenario, I have a list view on one page (this is in jQuery Mobile) with little thumb nails of graphs, next to the graph is a slider that is bound to a property of the same view model that causes the graph points to be recalculated. When you click on one of the list items, it moves to another page that shows a much larger version of the graph and lets you change the value by typing in a textbox (later, you'll be able to click directly on the graph). The binding looks something like this:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers["plot"] = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var qe = $(element);
            var page = qe.closest("div[data-role='page']");
            page.bind("pageshow", function () {
                ko.bindingHandlers["plot"].update(element, valueAccessor);
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var qe = $(element);
            var page = qe.closest("div[data-role='page']");
            var curr = $.mobile.activePage;
            var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var data = val.plotData();
            if(data && page.prop("id") == curr.prop("id")) {
                var marker = val.markerData();
                var opt = val.chartOptions();
                opt.yaxis.show = opt.xaxis.show = !qe.hasClass("graphThumb");
                marker.points.radius = opt.yaxis.show ? 5 : 3.5;
                $.plot(qe, [
                    data, 
                    marker
                ], opt);
            }
        }
    };
```

The `init` handler sets it up to draw the graph on a page show because flot doesn't work right when drawing to a non-visible `div`. The update will check if the currently displayed page is the same as the one with the binding and redraw the graph as required.

For the graphs in the list view, they are immediately draw by the `update` method and work correctly. However, for the initially hidden pages, the function to draw the graph fires, the graph draws, but the updates will no longer work. Then, worse, when you go back to the initial page, the function bound to the `pageshow` event fires, redraws the graphs, but now they've also quit updating.

The view model looks something like this:

```
var viewModel = (function () {
    this.current = ko.observable(0);
    this.plotData = ko.computed(function () {
        var points = [];
        // a bunch of calculations that depend on the value of current of this and other viewModels in a collection
        return points;
    }
}
```

I can stick a break point in the computed `plotData` and see that it is getting update correctly. It just that those updates aren't trigger the binding handler.

The HTML binding looks something like this:

```
<!-- the first, visible page -->
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: factors">
        <li data-bind="attr: {id: listId}">
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: idLink}">
                <div class="graphThumb" data-bind="plot: $data"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<!-- hidden details pages -->
<!-- ko foreach: factors -->
<div data-role="page" data-bind="attr: { id: id }"> 
    <div class="graphPlaceHolder" data-bind="plot: $data"></div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Update**: I changed my binding slightly because I realized that I can just call the `update` on the `pageshow` event handler, which simplifies things, but doesn't fix the problem. It seems that doing that won't make knockout update it's dependencies for the binding.

**Update**: another update, assigning `val.plotData()` to a variable didn't work, neither did including it in my `if` statement. However, I have another computed observable that depends on the the `current` value and another property of the parent view model that I could retrieve and add to my `if` statement that works! However, my solution is probably to specific to be generally useful. The short story is that knockout will reassess the dependencies of a binding with each update, so you need to make sure that it is evaluating something important regardless of any conditional logic or it will stop updating.

Comment: What happens if you move your `var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());` before the `if` in the `update` function?

Comment: @nemesv: I believe we're on the right track, but that doesn't actually help. The bound value doesn't actually change, it's the `plotData()` that does. However, if I add a line like `var data = val.plotData();` before the `if`, it still doesn't work. It seems that a simple assignment to a (potentially) unused variable isn't enough to convince knockout to update it's dependencies.

Comment: @nemesv: playing around some more, I should qualify my last comment. Adding the assignment of `data` does make it so all the other graph (other than the one I was looking at the single page view for) still work when coming back, and if I change one of those graphs it makes the one I initially clicked work again. However, the details view (the one that is hidden at initialization) still stubbornly doesn't work and when coming back to the main page, the one clicked doesn't work initially.

Comment: @nemesv: Okay, I found a way to get it working. The `val` by itself wasn't enough. Neither was `data` (which surprised me), but I found another property that did work and if I use it in the `if` statement knockout will dutifully keep track or it regardless of whether the `if` evaluated to true or not. If you want to write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as correct because you helped put me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: What do your factors look like? You are using this property in the binding. If they do not change (or are not observables) your binding won't be able to detect changes

Comment: @Anzeo: The factors are, in fact, the view model I included in the question. I `applyBindings` to a master view model that has an array of those view models.

Comment: @MattBurland that's your problem right there. Seeing as your viewmodel won't change (only properties on it) your binding won't update

Comment: @Anzeo: No, that's not the problem. Knockout is smart enough to build dependencies on the properties inside the view model. The bindings in knockout are implemented the same as ko.computed (as I understand it), so the binding will (or should) update when `plotData` changes, even though the viewmodel itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can wrap up and mark this question as answered, I will briefly summarize my experience.

Custom binding are implemented the same was as computed properties in Knockout (according to the KO docs), and one thing that computed properties do is reassess which properties they are dependent on every time they are executed. What this means, is if you have a conditional in computed property (or a custom binding), only the properties accessed in the branch of the condition that actually gets executed will be monitored for changes by knockout. So, for example, if you have a property like this:

```
var myComputedProperty = ko.computed(function() {
    if(this.myBool()) {
        $("#someElement").text(this.foo());
    }
    else {
        $("#someElement").text(this.bar());
    }
});
```

KO will keep track of the value of `myBool` and recalculate the property if it changes, but, if `myBool` is true, it will also track `foo`, if `myBool` is false, it will also track `bar`, but it won't track both - because it doesn't need to. Most of the time this works just fine.

In my case it failed because I had a conditional that wasn't part of the view model (and therefore wasn't observable) and I needed it to keep track of the view model properties regardless of whether or not the condition evaluated to true or false. So I had something that looked like this:

```
if(page.prop("id") == curr.prop("id")) {
    $("#someElement").text(this.foo());
}
```

Here the comparison is between the `id` of the page that the binding lives on and the `$.mobile.activePage` provided by jQuery Mobile (and, obviously not observable). If those `id` match, then knockout will update the binding when `foo` changes. However, if they don't, then knockout will lose the dependency on `foo` and even if the `id` do match at some later time, it will have lost the dependency and won't reevaluate when `foo` changes.

The way around this is to ensure that any properties that need to be tracked are evaluated regardless of the condition. So, something like this should solve the general case:

```
if(this.foo() && page.prop("id") == curr.prop("id")) {
    $("#someElement").text(this.foo());
}
```

As to why I needed the condition at all is because flot gets very confused when it tries to draw a graph to a non-visible div, so I need to skip drawing the graph when it wasn't the current page.